# how to search keywords in logfile using c#.net

Tags: c#, search, file

How to search the keywords in logfile using c#.net.

I had a log file which has some information preceded by a key word like ipaddress, userid etc., I need to parse the log file and get the data and show in grid view.

any suggetions in c#

Thank you,
jagadeesh kumar.

Comment: what is the Format of LogFile.. is it plain text file.. does it has data formatted in a particular manner

Comment: Just a suggestion, but you might want to try Microsoft Log Parser

Answer (score 0):

I don't know which format the file has exactly, but I would suggest you to use a `StreamReader` to read the file, then split it at `\n` and then process every single line...

This would then look somthing like this (not tested):

```
string wholeFile = "";
using(StreamReader str = new StreamReader(path))
{
   wholeFile = str.ReadToEnd();
}
string[] lines = wholeFile.Split('\n').Replace("\r", "");
for(int i = 0; i < lines.Length; i++)
{
   //parse the line
   string line = lines[i];
   if(line.Trim().StartsWith("ipaddress"))
   {
       string value = line.Trim().Replace("ipaddress", "");
       //Do something with the value here...
   }
}
```

You could also consider using [RegExp](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/prasad_1/regexppsd12062005021717am/regexppsd.aspx) to parse the file or even every line.

Good luck, Alex

Comment: 59.92.241.135 - - "2009-08-09 00:34:59  " "POST /processlogin.php?next=%2F HTTP/1.1" 302 22 "http://www.enggresources.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.9.0.13) Gecko/2009073022 Firefox/3.0.13 (.NET CLR 3.5.30729)"

Answer (score 0):

Use a reader to read the file, and then a regexp on each line to find what you want..

```
var reader = new StreamReader("path/to/file");
string line;
while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
{
   //parse the line here.   
}
```

See the [tutorial about regular expressions from Microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hs600312%28v=VS.100%29.aspx). Without seeing the format of the file it's not possible to give a more specific answer.